# Neo4j browser.post_connect_cmd does not work

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I run neo4j Version: 3.3.2 in a docker container and tried to configure a default style as described above.

- Grass file is accessible via HTTP (http://somedomain.com/resources/style.grass)
- CORS rules are set
- Command added to config: browser.post_connect_cmd=style http://somedomain.com/resources/style.grass

When i start my container with this config and run match (n) return n i see nothing.
Then i run `:style http://somedomain.com/resources/style.grass` and it works... Why?
That leads me to conclude that the grass file ifself (content) and the accessible of this file are not the problem.
It seems that there is an error with the default style configuration.
Do you have any tips to debug this? The logs are clean.

Comment: How do you set the config? Via an environment variable for docker?

Comment: In the neo4j.conf. Do you have a link for the environment variable I can set?

Comment: Ok, i found it in the docker entrypoknt script. But still no idea why it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. We added this property at the end of the neo4j.conf. After startup neo4j reorder the properties, put it at the 2nd place and accidentally add the 3rd property at the end of the 2nd, so that it’s not valid. We put it manually at the 2nd place and now it works.